# Probability problem 1

Tags: combinatorics

I just wanted to double check to see if I'm doing this problem correctly.

3 kids (Alice, Bob, and Carol) have to divide 15 different toys among themselves in a way that each kid gets 5 toys. How many ways can this be done?

I did C(15,5)/3

is that correct?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind your calculation?

Comment: There are 15 different toys, so you choose 5.. and then you divide them among the 3 kids because there are 3 different kids

Comment: So if there were $3$ kids dividing $3$ toys among themselves so that each gets $1$, there would be only $\frac{1}{3}C_{3,1} = \frac{1}{3}\binom{3}{1} = 1$ possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite—the number of ways to divide $15$ distinct objects into three distinct groups is

$$
\binom{15}{5, 5, 5} = \binom{15}{10} \binom{10}{5} = 90810720
$$

Comment: But aren't there then 6 (3!) ways to deal out the three groups among the children?

Comment: The *order* in which the kids get their toys is meant to be irrelevant, each kid only cares about which bundle of toys she got.

Comment: This is equivalent to $C(15,5)\cdot C(10,5)\cdot C(5,5)$. This means the first child chooses 5 out of 15, then the second chooses 5 out of the remaining 10, and the last child gets the rest.

Comment: Is $\binom{15}{5, 5, 5} $ a standard format for $\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5} $ ?  I haven't seen it used in this fashion before

Comment: I'd say it's pretty common in the U.S. at least.